# How do I position the button container at the bottom of a draggable modal box in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-modal

I have a modal box which has some content and at the bottom a button container which has two buttons. I want the button container to be always relative to the screen / viewport. Now the tricky part is the modal box is draggable. I can move it up and down but the height remains 100%.

Now if I give `position:absolute;bottom:0` to the button container, it sticks to the bottom of the modalbox. but when I push the modal downwards, the button container also gets pushed down.

How could I achieve positioning this always at the bottom of the screen regardless of the movement of modal ?

```
const ButtonContainer = styled(View)`
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: flex-end; 
  flex-direction: row; 
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  left: 0; 
`

const Container = styled(View)`
  padding-left: 15;
  padding-bottom: 60;
  padding-right: 15;
  padding-top: 15;
  height: 100%;
`

<Container>
   <ScrollView>
      {content}
   </ScrollView>
   <ButtonContainer>{buttons}</ButtonContainer>
</Container>
```

Comment: provide some more code that what you did.

Comment: @MayureshPatil, Added more code for the styles.

Comment: try:- remove height & try the property flex:1 to the container, OR take the height as a device dimension height.

Comment: @MayureshPatil This doesnt work :(

Comment: @Johan Correct, its a snapping modal with buttons at the bottoms. So even if the height of the modal changes, I want the buttons to stay at the bottom of screen (not at the bottom of modal).